# Backbone.js / Underscore.js : Why isn't my template escaping

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, xss, underscore.js

Using the latest backbone and underscore libraries (1.0.0/1.4.4) I can't figure out why my template isn't escaping like I expect. Here's a simplified version:

```
M = Backbone.Model.extend({});
V = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template("<%- attr %>"),
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
        return this;
    }
});
m = new M({attr: "<script>bad</script>"});
v = new V({model: m});
v.render();
console.log(v.el);
```

results in:

```
<div><script>bad</script></div>
```

which is, obviously, not escaped. I've verified that the template, executed as standalone code, escapes properly:

```
T = _.template("<%- attr %>");
console.log(T({attr: "<script>bad</script>"}));
```

yields the expected result of

```
&lt;script&gt;bad&lt;&#x2F;script&gt;
```

So somewhere the content is getting unescaped. If anyone knows where, or, better yet, how to prevent it, I'd be most grateful.

Stephen

---

Update:

Figured it out! Although the problem isn't the console *per se*, **mu**'s answer did point me in the right direction. To explain, I need to elaborate a little on the example code above so that it more accurately reflects my context. That context isn't actually console output but rather, unit testing. I want to verify that my code is correctly protecting against XSS attacks, so I had written the unit test (using mocha/sinon/chai/should):

```
v.$el.text().should.equal(m.escape("attr"));
```

That test was failing (unexpectedly), while the following test was passing (and I didn't think it should have been):

```
v.$el.text().should.equal(m.get("attr"));
```

The culprit turns out to the be the `toString()` method on the element object. That method, which `console.log()` uses, unescapes the content. That method is also (indirectly) used by jQuery in the `text()` function.

I'm not certain that this is universal in all browsers, but in my case using `.innerHTML()` avoids the `toString()` unescape. So the correct way to write my test is

```
v.el.innerHTML().should.equal(m.escape("attr"));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Answer (score 3):

I think your console is being overly "helpful" and confusing you. If we look at things closely, we'll see exactly what sort of chicanery is going here; I'm going to switch to `<b>` rather than `<script>` to avoid having to break the `<script>` into pieces to avoid confusing jsfiddle.

Consider this:

```
M = Backbone.Model.extend({});
V = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template("<%- attr %>"),
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
        return this;
    }
});
m = new M({attr: "<b>bad</b>"});
v = new V({model: m});
v.render();

$('body').append(v.el);
$('body').append($(v.el).text()).append('<br>');
$('body').append($(v.el).html());
```

You'll see three things on the page:

1. A literal `<b>bad</b>`.
2. A `bad` in bold.
3. A literal `<b>bad</b>`.

That exactly what we expect to see if the `attr` value **is** being escaped.

You, however, are looking at the console. So let us look at the console as well and toss a couple things at the bottom of the above JavaScript:

```
console.log(v.el);
console.log(v.el.innerHTML);
```

Now in the console we see this:

```
<div><b>bad</b></div>
&lt;b&gt;bad&lt;/b&gt;
```

But look closely at the first line, you should see the `<div>` and `</div>` appearing in purple (or whatever hilight color your console uses for DOM elements) while the `<b>bad</b>` is black (or whatever your console uses for plain text). So the `attr` is being properly escaped but your console is decoding things before displaying.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/5nYTd/